# json array to table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014. I can't use `openjson` to read the following array and convert it to table structure. My array looks like below. It can have more than 2 objects. I have a few other column as well in the table (`tableA`) along with array column:

```
[{"Id":1725,"Number":"12345","qty":1,"Block":true},
 {"Id":125,"Number":"1234544","qty":1,"Block":true}]
```

Created function below.

but it returns blank when I run it for my table as-

```
SELECT 
    dbo.fn_parse_json2xml(X.jsoncolumn) AS XML_Column
FROM 
    tableA AS X;
```

I could not get it to working.I apologize in advance if I missed something.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_parse_json2xml(
    @json    varchar(max)
)
RETURNS xml
AS

BEGIN;
    DECLARE @output varchar(max), @key varchar(max), @value varchar(max),
        @recursion_counter int, @offset int, @nested bit, @array bit,
        @tab char(1)=CHAR(9), @cr char(1)=CHAR(13), @lf char(1)=CHAR(10);

    --- Clean up the JSON syntax by removing line breaks and tabs and
    --- trimming the results of leading and trailing spaces:
    SET @json=LTRIM(RTRIM(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@json, @cr, ''), @lf, ''), @tab, '')));

    --- Sanity check: If this is not valid JSON syntax, exit here.
    IF (LEFT(@json, 1)!='{' OR RIGHT(@json, 1)!='}')
        RETURN '';

    --- Because the first and last characters will, by definition, be
    --- curly brackets, we can remove them here, and trim the result.
    SET @json=LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)-2)));

    SELECT @output='';
    WHILE (@json!='') BEGIN;

        --- Look for the first key which should start with a quote.
        IF (LEFT(@json, 1)!='"')
            RETURN 'Expected quote (start of key name). Found "'+
                LEFT(@json, 1)+'"';

        --- .. and end with the next quote (that isn't escaped with
        --- and backslash).
        SET @key=SUBSTRING(@json, 2,
            PATINDEX('%[^\\]"%', SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json))+' "'));

        --- Truncate @json with the length of the key.
        SET @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, LEN(@key)+3, LEN(@json)));

        --- The next character should be a colon.
        IF (LEFT(@json, 1)!=':')
            RETURN 'Expected ":" after key name, found "'+
                LEFT(@json, 1)+'"!';

        --- Truncate @json to skip past the colon:
        SET @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)));

        --- If the next character is an angle bracket, this is an array.
        IF (LEFT(@json, 1)='[')
            SELECT @array=1, @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)));

        IF (@array IS NULL) SET @array=0;
        WHILE (@array IS NOT NULL) BEGIN;

            SELECT @value=NULL, @nested=0;
            --- The first character of the remainder of @json indicates
            --- what type of value this is.

            --- Set @value, depending on what type of value we're looking at:
            ---
            --- 1. A new JSON object:
            ---    To be sent recursively back into the parser:
            IF (@value IS NULL AND LEFT(@json, 1)='{') BEGIN;
                SELECT @recursion_counter=1, @offset=1;
                WHILE (@recursion_counter!=0 AND @offset<LEN(@json)) BEGIN;
                    SET @offset=@offset+
                        PATINDEX('%[{}]%', SUBSTRING(@json, @offset+1,
                            LEN(@json)));
                    SET @recursion_counter=@recursion_counter+
                        (CASE SUBSTRING(@json, @offset, 1)
                            WHEN '{' THEN 1
                            WHEN '}' THEN -1 END);
                END;

                SET @value=CAST(
                    dbo.fn_parse_json2xml(LEFT(@json, @offset))
                        AS varchar(max));
                SET @json=SUBSTRING(@json, @offset+1, LEN(@json));
                SET @nested=1;
            END

            --- 2a. Blank text (quoted)
            IF (@value IS NULL AND LEFT(@json, 2)='""')
                SELECT @value='', @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 3,
                    LEN(@json)));

            --- 2b. Other text (quoted, but not blank)
            IF (@value IS NULL AND LEFT(@json, 1)='"') BEGIN;
                SET @value=SUBSTRING(@json, 2,
                    PATINDEX('%[^\\]"%',
                        SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json))+' "'));
                SET @json=LTRIM(
                    SUBSTRING(@json, LEN(@value)+3, LEN(@json)));
            END;

            --- 3. Blank (not quoted)
            IF (@value IS NULL AND LEFT(@json, 1)=',')
                SET @value='';

            --- 4. Or unescaped numbers or text.
            IF (@value IS NULL) BEGIN;
                SET @value=LEFT(@json,
                    PATINDEX('%[,}]%', REPLACE(@json, ']', '}')+'}')-1);
                SET @json=SUBSTRING(@json, LEN(@value)+1, LEN(@json));
            END;

            --- Append @key and @value to @output:
            SET @output=@output+@lf+@cr+
                REPLICATE(@tab, @@NESTLEVEL-1)+
                '<'+@key+'>'+
                    ISNULL(REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(@value, '\"', '"'), '\\', '\'), '')+
                    (CASE WHEN @nested=1
                        THEN @lf+@cr+REPLICATE(@tab, @@NESTLEVEL-1)
                        ELSE ''
                    END)+
                '</'+@key+'>';

            --- And again, error checks:
            ---
            --- 1. If these are multiple values, the next character
            ---    should be a comma:
            IF (@array=0 AND @json!='' AND LEFT(@json, 1)!=',')
                RETURN @output+'Expected "," after value, found "'+
                    LEFT(@json, 1)+'"!';

            --- 2. .. or, if this is an array, the next character
            --- should be a comma or a closing angle bracket:
            IF (@array=1 AND LEFT(@json, 1) NOT IN (',', ']'))
                RETURN @output+'In array, expected "]" or "," after '+
                    'value, found "'+LEFT(@json, 1)+'"!';

            --- If this is where the array is closed (i.e. if it's a
            --- closing angle bracket)..
            IF (@array=1 AND LEFT(@json, 1)=']') BEGIN;
                SET @array=NULL;
                SET @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)));

                --- After a closed array, there should be a comma:
                IF (LEFT(@json, 1) NOT IN ('', ',')) BEGIN
                    RETURN 'Closed array, expected ","!';
                END;
            END;

            SET @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)+1));
            IF (@array=0) SET @array=NULL;

        END;
    END;

    --- Return the output:
    RETURN CAST(@output AS xml);
END;

DECLARE @json varchar(max);

SET @json='{
"Person": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": [25, 26, 27],
    "Address": {
        "streetAddress":"21, 2nd Street",
        "city" :"New York",
        "state":"NY",
        "postalCode":"10021"
    },
        "PhoneNumbers": {
            "home":"212 555-1234",
            "fax":"646 555-4567"
        }
    }
}';

SELECT dbo.fn_parse_json2xml(@json);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code of `fn_parse_json2xml()`.

Comment: its in the link. do i still need to include it?

Comment: I can't see a function called `fn_parse_json2xml` in that link. There's one called `parseJSON`, however, that is a multiline table value function, where as you seem to be using a scalar function.

Comment: Show what *you* actually have as the error might well be in there. Also, there is no `fn_parse_json2xml` in the links article, don't let us guess what you've renamed as such. Apart from that, the link might go dead to have everything important in the post for future readers. Always keep an exe on that. Use links only for further reading and include the stuff your question actually is about in your post.

Comment: added it. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That doesn't look like the one in the link, I assume you've made (a lot) of changes. Why not use the code that was provided?

Comment: i have added the function i mentioned and removed the link thats all.

Answer (score 0):

That answer is really late, probably to late for you, but it might help someone else:

Assuming the structure is always the same you can transform your string to an XML rather easily:

```
DECLARE @jsonString NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'[{"Id":1725,"Number":"12345","qty":1,"Block":true},
 {"Id":125,"Number":"1234544","qty":1,"Block":true}]';

DECLARE @Converted XML=
CAST(REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (@jsonString,'[','')
      ,'{"Id":','<row><Id>')
        ,',"Number":','</Id><Number>')
          ,',"qty":','</Number><qty>')
            ,',"Block":','</qty><Block>')
              ,'},','</Block></row>')
                ,'}]','</Block></row>') AS XML);
```

--See the result

```
SELECT @Converted;

<row>
  <Id>1725</Id>
  <Number>"12345"</Number>
  <qty>1</qty>
  <Block>true</Block>
</row>
<row>
  <Id>125</Id>
  <Number>"1234544"</Number>
  <qty>1</qty>
  <Block>true</Block>
</row>
```

--This XML can be queries like here:

```
SELECT a.value('(Id/text())[1]','int') AS Id
      ,a.value('(Number/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Number
      ,a.value('(qty/text())[1]','int') AS qty
      ,a.value('(Block/text())[1]','bit') AS Block
FROM @Converted.nodes('/row') A(a);
```

The final result

```
Id      Number      qty Block
1725    "12345"     1   1
125     "1234544"   1   1
```